# Comparing two workbooks giving incorrect results

Tags: excel, vba

When running the below macro to compare 10,000 data rows in 3 columns, it's highlighting some of the records which are matching. Can someone help me to get this corrected?

```
Sub Compare()
Call Comparitor("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
End Sub
Sub Comparitor(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String)

Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim Z As Long
Dim diffnd As Long
Dim cnt1 As Long
Dim cnt2 As Long


cnt2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
cnt1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

'Color the mismatching cells in Yellow on Sheet2
For Z = 1 To cnt2
    For Y = 1 To cnt1
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(Z, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(Y, 1).Value Then
            For X = 2 To 22
                If Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(Z, X).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Cells(Y, X).Value Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet2).Cells(Z, X).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    diffnd = diffnd + 1
                End If
            Next
        Exit For
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting some workbook and worksheet objects to better manage your sheets. I'm not entirely sure this is the solution though. It appears the only place you didn't do that was in the beginning when you set cnt1 and cnt2. You also don't use the shtSheet1 or shtSheet2 variables, just string names so maybe its looking at different sheets?

I added in the wb, ws1, and ws2 to make it a little more readable though. Give it a shot and see what it does. Otherwise, I think your code is correct.

```
Sub Compare()
Call Comparitor("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
End Sub

Sub Comparitor(shtSheet1 As String, shtSheet2 As String)

Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim Z As Long
Dim diffnd As Long
Dim cnt1 As Long
Dim cnt2 As Long

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(shtSheet1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(shtSheet2)

cnt2 = ws2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
cnt1 = ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Color the mismatching cells in Yellow on Sheet2
For Z = 1 To cnt2
    For Y = 1 To cnt1
        If ws2.Cells(Z, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(Y, 1).Value Then
            For X = 2 To 22
                If Not ws2.Cells(Z, X).Value = ws1.Cells(Y, X).Value Then
                    ws2.Cells(Z, X).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    diffnd = diffnd + 1
                End If
            Next
        Exit For
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. But I'm still getting the same issue. And now only i realized that i have missed few lines of code. Which I have added below. If that helps.

Comment: I just ran into a situation earlier this week where I was coloring cells then sorting them. For some reason the cell colors didn't transition with the sort. Are you perhaps sorting later in the macro (not shown here)? My solution for this problem was to sort then color the cells.

Comment: I just published that latter part of the code below as answer due to a length. Perhaps that might explain the issue i'm facing.